# centos7 container is restarting continuously

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, devops

I am trying to run centos7 container using following Docker compose file and Dockerfile-

```
version: "2"    data:
    build:
      context: ./docker-build
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.data
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    command: bash
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7
RUN yum -y update
CMD /bin/sh
```

The container is restarting continuously I don't know the reason for it, How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Containers stop once their main process exits. In your case, the main process is a shell (`/bin/sh` or `bash`). A shell without a TTY attached exits immediately.

If you want to keep your container running, add a TTY to the container;

When using `docker run`;

Run a container interactively;

```
docker run -it centos:7 bash
```

Run the container in the background ("detached", `-d`);

```
docker run -dit centos:7 bash
```

When using a `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "2"
services:
  data:
    build:
      context: ./docker-build
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.data
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    command: bash
    tty: true
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it restarts is because of `restart: always` just delete it.